# In Teamcity, how to add reference of dll residing in parent directory of solution when running MSBuild?

Tags: c#, teamcity, msbuild-task

There is a project in c# which references few dlls that are present in the parent directory of solution. When I try to build using MSBuild in TeamCity, it fails because it cannot find the dlls. I tried providing the dlls as fixed path using Artifacts but no luck!

Could somebody please tell me if there is a way to add the reference of the dll present in parent directory in TeamCity?

Thanks.

Comment: I have this issue as well. In my case, it is for MonoMac.dll which is unsigned. I can get TeamCity to work if I sign a copy of MonoMac.dll and register it in the GAC using gacutil. However, if the project just refers to a folder with the dll, TeamCity does not pickup.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking MSBuild doesn't have any idea of what a solution is. MSBuild considers each project an independent entity and the files under the project folder are in its 'cone'. You are better off by staging the dlls in the project folder as a pre-build step of the project.

Comment: Thanks for the response Ritch.

Comment: Unfortunately, we are trying to use TeamCity to set up configuration management for an existing project and hence not feasible to change the code base. Is there no way to let TeamCity know that these dlls reside in parent directory (in folder commonDLLs) when building the project?

Comment: But references to dlls may be absolute paths :) Also it is definitelly possible to reference dlls in parent directories using `..\..\` stuff.

Comment: But how do we specify this path in TeamCity?

Comment: @Meghna - TeamCity's staging structure does make this really difficult. With the information that you've given us it seems like you are going to have to change some portion of the project structure and add a build script, or use something else besides TeamCity (like Jenkins).

Comment: Thanks for introducing me to Jenkins! Will give it a go.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to build your solution with MSBuild but without TeamCity. If it works check whether your dlls are being checked out during the build.

Teamcity does nothing else than invoking msbuild.exe.

Comment: Sorry about any confusion I might have caused, let me explain the full problem here...

Comment: So you build each project using by it's own build configuration? If this is the case, you may try to use artifact, not snapshot dependency

Comment: Why just building *.sln file does not work for your? I don't think you really need all that complexity. You have solution file -- just add build step with MSBuild runner.

Comment: No, it doesn't work that way. May be because there are five different projects that are referenced within the solution and they are all in separate directories.

Comment: @the_joric You are correct in that TeamCity invokes msbuild to build, but it does have its own 'unique' way of extracting projects from version control and staging the output. Its a rather different concept and can cause some problems. I like TeamCity, but when using Mercurial's sub-repos, TeamCity completely broke for me due to the way it deals with staging and folders.

Comment: Sorry, but I am not following you :) Teamcity pulls what you've asked it to pull and builds what you've asked it to build — it does not any magic behind the scenes. However — for subrepos it may be tricky (I never used them though)

Comment: @the_joric I've had quite a bit of difficulty with TeamCity's VCSRoots and how they stage sources for the build runner. And yes, they do a bit of magic behind the scenes.